# failed: ImportError: cannot import name splitgophertype

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, robotframework

I get this error when I import the python modules to Robot Framework. But when I run the .py modules independently outside it works fine. Can someone tell me why do I get splitgophertype error

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\karthicm\DigitalMP3_Project\__init__.html' in table 'Settings': Importing test library 'C:\RF_Library\CP_Web_SignInPage.py' failed: ImportError: cannot import name splitgophertype
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\RF_Library\CP_Web_SignInPage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib_Operations_UILink import ClickLink
  File "C:\RF_Library\lib_Operations_UILink.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lib_TestSetUp import is_element_present, Fnc_WaitForPageToLoad,\
  File "C:\RF_Library\lib_TestSetUp.py", line 6, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.extension_connection import ExtensionConnection
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 22, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 23, in <module>
    import urllib2 as url_request
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\urllib2.py", line 110, in <module>
    from urllib import (unwrap, unquote, splittype, splithost, quote,
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Python27
  C:\RF_Library
  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
  C:\Python27
  C:\RF_Library
  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver
  C:\Users\karthicm\DigitalMP3_Project
  C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
  C:\Python27\DLLs
  C:\Python27\lib
  C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
  C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
  .
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\karthicm\DigitalMP3_Project\__init__.html' in table 'Settings': Importing test library 'C:\RF_Library\lib_AmazonMusic.py' failed: ImportError: cannot import name splitgophertype
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\RF_Library\lib_AmazonMusic.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lib_Operations_Common import is_element_present, ConvertToSeconds, FloatEquals
  File "C:\RF_Library\lib_Operations_Common.py", line 6, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.extension_connection import ExtensionConnection
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 22, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 23, in <module>
    import urllib2 as url_request
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\urllib2.py", line 110, in <module>
    from urllib import (unwrap, unquote, splittype, splithost, quote,
```

My test library imports are

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 import datetime
 import os.path
 import lib_CreateMasterDictionary
```

One of the methods in the same test library which I am trying to use is

```
def initiate_setup(self, profile="default"):
"""
This function is initial setup for each test script
The function takes 2 agrument - self and a profile for Firefox, only if necessary
"""
try:
    current_profile = False
    if TARGET_BROWSER == "Firefox" and profile:
        current_profile = setup_firefox_profile(profile) 
    self.wd_handle = webdriver_initiate(current_profile)
    if TARGET_BROWSER == "Chrome" and profile:
        setup_Chrome_plugin(self.wd_handle, profile)
    #if TARGET_BROWSER == "IE" and profile:
        # Developer for this part of the code did not have access to IE, also IE sucks.
    self.wd_handle.implicitly_wait(5)
    self.wd_handle.maximize_window()
    self.base_url = HOMEPAGE_AMAZON
    self.verificationErrors = []

    today = datetime.date.today()
    string_today = str(today)
    string_today = string_today.replace('-', '')
    self.string_today = string_today

    if not os.path.exists(TEST_DIRECTORY+"/"+string_today):
        os.makedirs(TEST_DIRECTORY+"/"+string_today)

    self.resultFile = open(RESULT_FILE, 'a')  # opening file for output
    result_file2 = self.resultFile

    global ElementMappingDictionary
    Obj_MasterDictObj = lib_CreateMasterDictionary.CLS_MasterDictionaryBySheet(Str_ExcelPath, Str_SheetName)
    ElementMappingDictionary = Obj_MasterDictObj.Fnc_ReturnElementMasterDict(Str_ExcelPath, Str_SheetName)

except Exception as ex:
    if not ex:
        print ex
```

Comment: Please indent your questions appropriately, it is almost unreadable as it stands.

Comment: can you actually show us some code which causes this error?

Comment: import Selenium2Library.Selenium2Library in eclipse also results in the same error